# How to change the rate of increase/decrease in an HTML slider

Tags: html, slider

If I have a slider and the minimum value is 0, and the maximum value is 10, then you can drag it and move it from 0 to 10, and everywhere in between. Is there any way I could make it "jump" from 0, to 1, to 2, like only moving 1 at a time? Or moving 0.1? As in it wouldn't slide fluidly, it would jump along ten spaces, or 100 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just set a [`step` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range) like:

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="10" step="1">
```

Comment: I had a feeling it would be that simply but I just couldn't think of the word for it-Thanks!